# REGEXREPLACE on column with numerical and text values

Tags: regex, excel, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to remove a trailing `.` character from each entry in a column, my formula is

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "\.$"; "")`

Applying this to my data:

```
0
aa.
cc
```

I get an error for the first value `Function REGEXREPLACE parameter 1 expects text values. But '0' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text.`

Trying to convert it to text using `T()`:

`=REGEXREPLACE(T(A1);"\.$"; "")`

gives no error, but the cell A1 is empty instead of `0`. How do I apply such a formula to a column with miced data types?

[image]

Comment: `=REGEXREPLACE(T(A1), "\.$", "")` works for me.

Comment: for me it doesn't.. It takes away the zero.

Comment: If A1 doesn't contain text, T will return an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1&"";"\.$"; "")
```

or

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1);"\.$"; "")
```

Comment: Works well! Is the number is coerced to text by concatenation with the empty string?